# Xcode radio buttons- Changing background image of a button when another button is pressed

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode5

I'm trying to implement my own basic radio buttons, such that only one of them can be selected at a time.
Here's the code I'm using->

```
- (IBAction)btn2Pressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    [btn1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"circle-uncheck.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    btn2pressed = YES;
    btn1pressed = NO;
}


- (IBAction)btn1Pressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    [btn2 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"circle-uncheck.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    btn1pressed = YES;
    btn2pressed = NO;
}
```

But it's not working, i.e. the image of the other button isn't changing. :(

I'm not able to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: What are the `btn1` and `btn2` variables? Are they IBOutlets? Are you sure they're linked to the buttons?

Comment: Yes, btn1 and btn2 are linked to btn1Pressed and btn2Pressed IBActions respectively.

Answer (score 1):

When you press any of the 2 buttons, you set the background image to `circle-uncheck.png`. How is it ever be changed to `checked`? It will stay `unchecked` forever, I guess.

**EDIT** (due to you comment below):

If you set the background images **initially** in the Interface Builder, they will be changed to `circle-uncheck.png` as soon as a button is pushed, and they are apparently never be set to the `checked` state.
You had to modify your code to something like

```
- (IBAction)btn2Pressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    [btn1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"circle-uncheck.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn2 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"circle-check.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    btn2pressed = YES;
    btn1pressed = NO;
}

- (IBAction)btn1Pressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    [btn2 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"circle-uncheck.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"circle-check.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    btn1pressed = YES;
    btn2pressed = NO;
}
```

Comment: I'm setting the background images in the interface builder attribute inspector.

Comment: You're right! Thanks for pointing that out, I've changed my code, but the background images still don't change. :(

Comment: I assume you have changed my code (UIImage imageNamed:@"circle-check.png") so that one of your existing "checked" images is used?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't wish to use a `UISegmentedControl`, I would create a `IBOutletCollection` and link all of your radio buttons to it.

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *radioButtons;
```

In Interface builder I would set a selected state background image and an normal state background image.

Or in code something like:

```
[btn1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"circle-uncheck.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"circle-check.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Then I would create one control function:

```
-(IBAction)didSelectRadioButton:(id)sender
{
    for(UIButton *button in self.radioButtons){
        button.selected = NO;
    }

    UIButton *selectedButton = (UIButton *)sender;
    selectedButton.selected = YES;
}
```

A simple radio solution using UIButtons, and scalable :)

W