# Can we add action programatically to UIbuttons added from Interface Builder?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I created three buttons from the interface builder and linked to it:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btn1;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btn2;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btn3;
```

Now I loaded them in a array like this:

```
NSArray *array=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:btn1,btn2,btn3, nil];
```

Now for some reason I want to link up all of them to same selector and tried this:

```
for(UIButton *myButton in array)
{

    [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(onBtnPress:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

}
```

Defined the selector as:

```
-(void)onBtnPress:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"PRESSED");

}
```

But it's not working and throwing this error:

[image]
**EDIT:**

If I do this on the same viewController that I linked the button it works. But if I pass the buttons to another class and do this it is throwing error.

I am passing it to another class as follows:

In the viewController:

```
RadioButton *radioSet=[[RadioButton alloc]initWithButtons:@[btn1,btn2,btn3]];
```

In Radio Button Class:

```
@interface RadioButton()
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSMutableArray *inactiveBtn;
@end

@implementation RadioButton
- (instancetype)initWithButtons:(NSArray *)buttons
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
         self.initialBtnList=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:buttons];
        [self initialState];
}
    return self;
}

-(void)initialState
{

    for(UIButton *myButton in initialBtnList)
{

    [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(onBtnPress:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
}
```

Comment: You should add the error message to your question.

Comment: Error message is on the link nothing on the log though. And Yes if I do this on the same viewController that I linked the button it works. But if I pass the buttons to another class and do this it is throwing error. What am I missing here?

Comment: Have you heard of `IBOutletCollections`? Real neat. I would look them up.

Comment: There's nothing in your question about passing the buttons to another class. You need to show how you're doing that, and fully explaining your setup. Don't do that in comments, edit your question.

Comment: What's the error you encounter ? The screenshot above is not showing an error.

Comment: When you pass the buttons to another class, your target will remain as the older class and it will crash if it isn't alive. What exactly are you trying to do? I'm sure there is a better way.

Comment: I am trying to create class for custom radio button :)

Comment: Oh i should pass the target too then?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/24089820/2982796

Comment: My need is little more complicated than that so!

Comment: I thought it solved the problem but turned out that it was calling the function on the target and not of the class lol. I can't think anymore 5 AM already :(.

Comment: Anybody up with the solution? How can we change the target of the button to the class to which it is being passed?